# Usage of Named Function Expressions vs pure Functions in HotTowel SPA

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

I have noticed that [js code](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal) in SPA Jump Start course on PluralSight mixes the use Named Function Expressions vs "regular" functions....
For example:

- all /services/*.js (expect dataservice.js) and viewmodels/shell.js use regular function declaration (e.g. `function doSomething() { //...}` )
- all /viewmodels/*.js (except shell.js) and /dataservices/datacontext.js use Named Function Expressions (e.g. `var doSomething = function() { //...}` )

I somewhat understand the difference between the two, but in terms of SPA design with Durandal which one should be used?

If there no difference, is there a particular syle that is recommended (e.g. when using AMD w/ require js use NFEs for functions that will be exported/returned and refular functions for internal methods or something)?

Comment: @John Papa I would appreciate you input as well!

Comment: I have always found this to be a great general reference on the overall topic (function expressions vs. function declarations): http://kangax.github.io/nfe/.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer Thanks...I have read this doc before. It is really good, but I am trying to understand if the author had reasons for using one style vs another throughout the code base.

Comment: If you look at a file like this one: https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/blob/master/SPAJumpStart/App/services/datacontext.js. The functions at the bottom are created as function declarations, because they are created after the return value and function declarations are hoisted and evaluated when the file is loaded rather than when execution gets to that line of code.  Just a way to be able to segment off some internal functions at the bottom that are never exported in this case.

Comment: @@RP Niemeyer That is what I thought also, but then again look at models.js for example...all functions that are exported are not named and are declared after return...So it is not consistent...

Comment: I personally think that that is a kind of confusing style to use, but technically the functions declarations just allow you to put them anywhere in the block even after the return.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer I agree - It is confusing :) That is why I posted the question (hoping for some input from John Papa). I wanted to know if it was matter of style and in general what is recommended (use NFE or not) for SPAs with Durandal

Comment: My feeling is that it doesn't matter.  The only advantage/reason to use a function declaration is hoisting.